# SSH remote forwarded port doesn't accept external connection (even with `GetewayPorts yes`)

Tags: networking, ssh, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel, reverse-tunnel

I am trying to set a reverse/remote SSH port forward, using this schema where the Apache Linux server forwards the port 80 to the SSH server.

[image: Schema]

So

1. On the SSH server I changed the configuration to add the `GatewayPorts yes` option:

   [image: screenshot]
2. Restarted the SSH server using `service ssh restart`.
3. On the Apache server I used the command

   ```
   ssh -f -N -R *:7849:localhost:80 vdiallonort@10.65.0.4
   ```
4. On the SSH server I typed

   ```
   netstat -ap |grep -w 7849
   ```

   The result is:

   > ```
   > tcp  0 0 127.0.0.1:7849 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN  
   > tcp6 0 0 ::1:7849 :::* LISTEN
   > ```

From the SSH server if I connect to `localhost:7849` I will see the webpage coming from Apache server but not if I connect from the TestClient and hit `10.65.0.4:7849`.

What did I miss? It feels like the `GatewayPorts yes` instruction doesn't work.

Comment: add `-g` parameter to ssh line.

Comment: I tried but still the same problem, localhost work fine but not from another server

Comment: Check if you have another `GetewayPorts` line in the config. In a case when two or more such lines could apply, I believe only the first one matters.

Comment: Thanks I looked at that but couldn't see anything, here a screenshot of my ssh configuration :
https://ibb.co/g0YgSU

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The screenshot shows a file with text

> This is the ssh client system-wide configuration file. See ssh_config(5) for more information.

It's `ssh_config`, *client* configuration file. `GatewayPorts yes` should be in your SSH *server* configuration file, `sshd_config` (mind the `d`).